# Identifying insect in Sri Lanka

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I saw this one in our garden in Colombo, Sri Lanka. It seemed to be hiding from the harsh sunlight that was there. I have never seen this bug before. Anyone know what bug this could be? [image]

Comment: Does it jump away if you disturb it?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a [springtail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springtail) (Collembola). I'm not familiar with Sri Lankan fauna, but the overall body plan (kind of oval, pudgy, short-legged) reminds me of a subgroup of springtails, the [Poduromorpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poduromorpha).

You can see similar-looking species in the Superfamily Neanuroidea, which are an example group in the Poduromorpha order:

[image]

<sup>*Brachystomella parvula* from UK; Credit: Andy Murray (2012); Source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Brachystomella_parvula_juvenile_(8204572060).jpg)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Red Poduromorph Springtails (family Neanuridae) ; Credit: Elahi Rayan (2018); Source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Poduromorpha_%E3%80%8B_Neanuroidea_%E3%80%8B_Neanuridae.jpg)</sup>

Comment: FYI springtails are not *insects* but a closely related group of [hexapods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexapoda)

Comment: Agreed all the way down to superfamily; going any further than that really needs a slide-mounted specimen, and (given the OP location) may actually end with a species that is as yet nameless.

Comment: @Arthur thanks for the comment. To clarify for others reading my post: I am only proposing this superfamily as a likely correct answer. I only include the specific species (found 1000s km away in the UK) for the sake of demonstrating visually the common body plan seen in the superfamily. I have no idea what the OP's species is, and Arthur is probably correct that neither does science :p.